# Constraints Conflict UICollectionVIew

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, constraints, autoresizingmask

I am getting the following error output:

```html
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-05-29 20:02:36.092 City[353:33890] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
 Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
 Try this: 
  (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
  (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
 (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1461c600 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x14629380.midX == + 80.2612>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1461c630 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0x14629380(64.5225)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1451e6a0 h=--& v=--& UIView:0x1460ac80.midX == + 172.364>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1451e6d0 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0x1460ac80(283.272)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1461dbd0 UITextView:0x14b15000'Fabian Delph has been dro...'.leading == UIView:0x14629380.leading + 8>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1451e500 UITextView:0x14b15000'Fabian Delph has been dro...'.leading == UIView:0x1460ac80.leading + 8>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1461dbd0 UITextView:0x14b15000'Fabian Delph has been dro...'.leading == UIView:0x14629380.leading + 8>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

All of the views in my `UICollectionViewCell` are created programmatically in the below method, with the exception of the `messageTextView` which is defined in storyboard. I know there is an issue with some of the autoresizing constaints, however I am not sure how to solve it. If I use the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` on the entire cell, nothing is shown on screen in the collectionView. I am having trouble understanding what `UiView` the constraints are referring to, and what I can do to solve this issue.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("message_cell" , forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DisplayMessageCollectionViewCell

    let textBubbleView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1)
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return view
    }()
    let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        return imageView
    }()
    profileImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cell.messageTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    //textBubbleView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    if let messageText =  chat_m[indexPath.row].text {
        cell.messageTextView.text = messageText
        cell.messageTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        let sender_image = chat_m[indexPath.row].sender_image
        cell.senderID = chat_m[indexPath.row].sender?.id
        cell.frameView = view
        profileImageView.image = sender_image
        let size = CGSizeMake(250, 1000)
        let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading.union(.UsesLineFragmentOrigin)
        let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: messageText).boundingRectWithSize(size, options: options, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)], context: nil)
        print(estimatedFrame.width)

        if let user_id = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userId") {
            if (user_id == chat_m[indexPath.row].sender?.id) {
                profileImageView.hidden = true
                    cell.messageTextView.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.width - estimatedFrame.width - 16 - 8, 0, estimatedFrame.width + 16, estimatedFrame.height + 20)
                    textBubbleView.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.width - estimatedFrame.width - 16 - 8 - 16, -4, estimatedFrame.width + 16 + 8 + 10, estimatedFrame.height + 20 + 6)


                    textBubbleView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: (69/255.0), green: (209/255.0), blue: (153/255.0), alpha: 1.0)
                    cell.messageTextView.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            }
            else {
                profileImageView.hidden = false
                cell.messageTextView.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                textBubbleView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha:1)
                    cell.messageTextView.frame = CGRectMake(48 + 3, 0, estimatedFrame.width + 15, estimatedFrame.height + 20 )
                    textBubbleView.frame = CGRectMake(48, 0, estimatedFrame.width + 20, estimatedFrame.height + 20 )


            }
        }

    }
    cell.addSubview(textBubbleView)
    cell.addSubview(profileImageView)
    cell.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-4-[v0(30)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": profileImageView]))
    cell.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[v0(30)]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": profileImageView]))
    cell.sendSubviewToBack(textBubbleView)
    cell.addSubview(profileImageView)
    cell.bringSubviewToFront(profileImageView)
    cell.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.messageTextView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: textBubbleView, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    cell.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:cell.messageTextView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: textBubbleView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 8))

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your debug log:

```
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1461dbd0 UITextView:0x14b15000'Fabian Delph has been dro...'.leading == UIView:0x14629380.leading + 8>",
 "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1451e500 UITextView:0x14b15000'Fabian Delph has been dro...'.leading == UIView:0x1460ac80.leading + 8>"
```

You have two constraints (0x1461dbd0, 0x1451e500) with the same value that are bind to the different views. which may conflict.

Your `textBubbleView` has different frame that depends on your logic, and don't have properly constraints (now it's using the default translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints which has value YES). You have the commented line, it's the right way, but you also must set the constraints for  `textBubbleView` in a way you did for profileImageView (leading, trailing, top, height - it depends on your requirement.

If you want your `messageTextView` to have the layout depend on `textBubbleView` - 
remove old constraints first and re-add it:

```
[messageTextView removeConstraints: [messageTextView constraints]];
```